# pyspark is unable to find KafkaUtils.createDirectStream

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark, kafka-python

I have the following pyspark script, which suppose to connect to a local kafka cluster:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from operator import add
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
## Constants
APP_NAME = "PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount"
##OTHER FUNCTIONS/CLASSES

def main():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
if __name__ == "__main__":

   main()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/hello1.py", line 16, in main
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
AttributeError: type object 'KafkaUtils' has no attribute 'createDirectStream'
```

What should I do in order to have access to KafkaUtils.createDirectStream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Spark 1.3.0 and Python version of `createDirectStream` has been introduced in Spark 1.4.0. Spark 1.3 provides only Scala and Java implementations.

If you want to use direct stream you'll have to update your Spark installation.